# Can I immediately start a new ajax request after aborting for the previous one?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a web application where the HTTPs handshake take place for every connection and I'm determined to find out why. The HTTP keep-alive is working, so it's something else that forces a request to start a new HTTPs handshake when it shouldn't.

I have something like this (pseudocode):

```
   startNewRequest() {
     if (oldRequest)
        oldRequest.abort(); // abort old request
     oldRequest = $.ajax(); // start new request
   }
```

The request object is XMLHttpRequest returned by jQuery's ajax method. Everytime when I start a request, I abort for the previous request.

My questions is that whether this would force a new request to start a HTTP handshake because the old one hasn't been completed. The requests are regular POST. Do I need to explicit wait for about() to complete before starting off a new request so to take advantage of the HTTP keep alive?

I do get a call in the error callback for $.ajax() for every request I abort. Do I need to start a new request only after I get a callback in the error handler?

Comment: probably you need to use $.when() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: jQuery .always() "Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected" See http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use complete or error in $.ajax

#### Complete:

```
$.ajax({
   url : RequestUrl,
   complete : function(){
       // Do something when request complete
   }
});
```

#### Error:

```
$.ajax({
   url : RequestUrl,
   error: function(){
       // Do something when an error occurred when the request is done
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url : yoururl,
   success : function(){
       // Do whatever
       // oldRequest = $.ajax();
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code snippet solves the problem which the OP had? It appears that you're only addressing the event of a successful request, which is most certainly **not** what this question is about.